# Need help in solving parametric equation problem.

Tags: calculus, parametric

While solving problems in my preparation for exam I faced parametric equation related to calculus. 
[image]

I can deal with finding tangent line but I am in no way being able to relate x to y by solving for t in both equations. It seems that there is a trick that I am not being able to see. Can some one help me with this by just giving direction.

Comment: I don't see where in the question you're actually prompted to solve for $y$ in terms of $x$, or vice versa.

Comment: I mean if I solve for t in the (x,t) and (y,t) equation than I can equal the expression that contains only x to the one that contains only y so as to form an equation of y,x of which I am going to find the tangent line of

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I do suggest you use

$\frac {dy}{dx} = \frac{\frac {dy}{dt}}{\frac {dx}{dt}}$

This is just an application of the chain rule.

It is possible to put this into a more familiar form:

$9x^2 + y^2 =$$ \frac {9t^2}{(1+t^2)^2} + \frac {4-4t^2+t^4}{(1+t^2)^2}\\
\frac {4+5t^2 + t^4}{(1+t^2)^2} = \frac {(t^2 + 1)(4t^2 + 1)}{(1+t^2)^2}\\
 \frac {(4t^2 + 1)}{(1+t^2)}\\
 \frac {-(1-2t^2) + 2 (1+t^2)}{(1+t^2)} = -y + 2$

$9x^2 + y^2 =  -y + 2$

Tells us that our parameterziation gives us an ellipse.

Answer (score 3):

The formula for slope with parametric equations is

$${dy\over dx}= {{dy\over dt}\over{dx\over dt}}$$

If you can get the derivatives ${dy\over dt}$and${dx\over dt}$, you will have ${dy\over dx}$ in terms of $t$ and you would plug in $t=2$ to get the slope of the tangent line.  The equation would then be found using the point-slope formula.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me. Can you explain why this formula makes sense.

Comment: What did you get for ${dy\over dt}$ and${dx\over dt}$?

Comment: I got $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-6t}{1-t^2}$. What did you get for the individual derivatives?

Comment: Ok thanks I got it!!! :D

Comment: Yes now I got the same result as you. Previously I made careless mistake.

Comment: Excellent! If the answer is useful, you can mark it as an accepted answer.